# Switch buffers in vim without saving to a currently modified file

Tags: vim, switching

Ok, I'm a vim user with the Minibufexl plugin which shows buffer tabs, I've mapped Shift+J and Shift+K to switch between tabs. One thing that frequently frustrates me is while editing a file, and switching to another buffer, I *HAVE* to write to the current file and then switch.

Eg, I have foo.cpp and foo.h open in two buffers, and I'm editing foo.cpp and haven't saved it,  I need to check foo.h to see a function definition. I then use either the alternate files quickly plugin (a.vim) or my shortcut above. This is where I have to save before switching, it gets annoying quickly.

I don't know which search query to use in the Googles so I'm asking here, my apologies if it's misleading.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want to have

```
set hidden
```

in your `.vimrc` file. Read a (little) more about the [hidden](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ#hidden) option and [hidden buffers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#buffer-hidden)

Comment: your first link is just a redirect from vim.wikia.com to the vimdoc page in the second link.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Leaving_modified_buffers may also be of interest.

Comment: @jamessan - yes I know, but the page it redirects to has single quotes in the URL and I couldn't get it to appear properly using markdown, so I used the redirect address instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to use split windows. For example, while editing foo.c, execute

```
:split foo.h
```

That will open foo.h in a window above foo.c. You can move between windows with `^W^W` (Ctrl-W Ctrl-W) and maximize the current window with `^W_`. You can find more information on this by executing

```
:help windows
```

Comment: I used to do that a while ago but my pinky became sore quickly, and I didn't really want to remap Cntrl to Shift but if I move to a machine without my handy .vimrc file, I will absolutely follow your hint. 

Thanks.